# scala play framework define action named 'new'

Tags: scala, playframework

Is it possible to define a function/Action name `new`?

eg:

`def new = Action { ... }`

more precisely if I want to create a route named `new` how can I accomplish this with Scala and Play framework?

P.S.

I suppose it is not possible due to the fact `new` is a keyword.

And for creating a route `new` it is enough to map to an action that is not exactly the same name but for example `_new`.

Anyway I am asking  because maybe there is a way to define a function in Scala named new.

Comment: You can surround `new` with back-ticks, but I'm not sure the routes compiler supports that syntax.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately the routes compiler doesn't support that syntax. maybe for the next version. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route name doesn't require to be the same as name of the action, as `new` is reserved word in Scala you can't use it directly as action's name so rename it i.e. to:

```
def newAction = Action { ... }
```

and then use route like:

```
GET   /new   controllers.Application.newAction
```

In general using restricted keywords for names of methods, views, variables, etc. etc. is bad idea, it likes to revenge especially after several hours of work.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, you can use backticks around a method, variable or what else you like, to give them names which are reserved keywords.

So in your case, you can use `` def `new` = ??? ``.

Comment: Yes thank you. But the route syntax in play framework doesn't accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this restriction in the play framework. Thanks for the hint.